# Joomla Installation in Subdir, index.php in root?

Tags: joomla

Is it possible to install Joomla in a sub directory and move the index.php to the root. I know this can be done with WordPress but I can't seem to find the Joomla Equivalent.

I am already using a redirect, not a very good one.

I really don't want all the joomla folders clogging up my root directory.

Thanks in advance,
sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Joomla! does not have a documented way of doing this. You might be able to change the code where the `JPATH_BASE` constant and `JURI` class are defined, but you'd definitely have to hack the core to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Would making a virtual host help?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but I've found solution for this question that dont force You to hak a system.
To redirect Joomla You can do (it works with: Joomla! 2.5) :
1. Put .htaccess file to Your root web directory (often it's: `public_html`) with this code:

```
# .htaccess main domain to subfolder redirect
# Copy and paste the following code into the .htaccess file
# in the public_html folder of your hosting account
# make the changes to the file according to the instructions.

# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on

# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/

# Don't change these lines.
# You may have to comment this if You i.e. have na `index.php` file which You dont want load
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]

# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?{HTTP_HOST}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /subfolder/index.php [L]
```

1. In Your Joomla `config.php` file, chage this line:

   `public $live_site = 'http://www.your-domain.com';`

Change Your domain for Your actual domain.